# Facebook scraper error - return 404.html

Tags: php, html, facebook, .htaccess

I have some problem with Facebook scrape.
I have domain: www.prodajapasa.com and Facebook scrape root domain and other pages very well, but pages like: 
http://www.prodajapasa.com/prodaja_boo-prelepi-stenci-iz-2-legla_53754.html 
...
he can't read. When I go to see what scraper sees i get this information:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="404.html";</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=404.html"></noscript>
</head></html>
```

I have .htaccess file:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1&rasa=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
redirect /poklon.html /psi-na-poklon.html
redirect /adddog.html /adddog2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html  
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week" 

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

 # 1 Month for all your static assets
 <filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesMatch>

 # 1 DAYS for rss feeds and robots
 <filesMatch ".(xml|txt)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
 # 25 DAYS for slova
 <filesMatch ".(ttf|woff)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2160000, public, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>

 # 4 HOURS for your real articles files
 <filesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
```

Comment: When I go to http://www.prodajapasa.com/prodaja_boo-prelepi-stenci-iz-2-legla_53754.html I also get redirected to 404.html

Comment: Really? And root domain you can see?

Comment: I can access the URL in my browser, but when I use a tool such as http://web-sniffer.net/, I get the minimal document that redirects to the 404 page as well. (Which is bad practice, btw. – redirecting elsewhere will mess up the HTTP status codes the client gets to see, which search engines don’t particularly like.)

Comment: Ok, but I don't have redirections. Maybe it's some error of configuration on server. How can I allow facebook and other agents in .htaccess file to read my content?